# PowerBI authentication C#

Tags: c#, azure, active-directory, oauth-2.0, powerbi

I am wondering if anyone can assist me, I am having a problem with power bi. What I am trying to do is push some data into Power BI. I am finding it difficult to find an approach were a user can enter there user name and password and then I will be able to push data into the Power BI account.

I am getting stuck at the first hurdle of getting an Access Token. I just keeping bad request. I have also tried getting-started-for-dotnet which for some strange reason I can also not get to work.

Error given is: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.

Registered as Web application

```
public class PowerBICreds
{
    public string resourceUri  { get; set; }
    public string clientID     { get; set; }
    public string grantType    { get; set; }
    public string username     { get; set; }
    public string password     { get; set; }
    public string scope        { get; set; }
    public string clientSecret { get; set; }
    public string loginAddress { get; set; }
    public string baseurl      { get; set; }
}

public static string AccessToken(PowerBICreds Creds)
{

    StringBuilder Httpbody = new StringBuilder();
    Httpbody.Append("resource=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Creds.resourceUri));
    Httpbody.Append("&client_id=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Creds.clientID));
    Httpbody.Append("&grant_type=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Creds.grantType));
    Httpbody.Append("&username=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Creds.username));
    Httpbody.Append("&password=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Creds.password));
    Httpbody.Append("&scope=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Creds.scope));
    Httpbody.Append("&client_secret=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Creds.clientSecret));

    using (WebClient web = new WebClient())
    {
        web.Headers.Add("client-request-id", Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
        web.Headers.Add("return-client-request-id", "true");

        string jsonstring = web.UploadString(Creds.loginAddress, Httpbody.ToString());

        dynamic result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonstring);

        try
        {
            return result.access_token;
        }
        catch
        { 


        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Update when I try the sample to show how to use the Power BI API provided by Mircosoft here https://github.com/PowerBI/getting-started-for-dotnet

Additional technical information: 
Correlation ID: f1281ec2-4e09-41e6-8847-3acfd3eb7922 
Timestamp: 2015-12-04 22:48:58Z 
AADSTS65005: The client application has requested access to resource 'https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api'. This request has failed because the client has not specified this resource in its requiredResourceAccess list.

Comment: Couple of questions to help us understand your issue more.  1) What is the detail error message you're getting?  2) how did you register you app - is it a client application or web application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error you got when using our sample application may mean that the app you registered with AAD doesn't request any permission for Power BI. Try using our new app registration page at http://dev.powerbi.com/apps. If you just want to push data into Power BI, you just need the dataset read/write permission.

Comment: Okay got this to work but the apps are not showing in the azure portal when I create them, How do I view them..?

Comment: If you log into the Azure portal with the same account that you used to register, you should see the apps somewhere in the Azure AD section. You can always create a new app if you can't find the old one.

Comment: @JoshCaplan-MSFT Hi, Josh! Using dev.powerbi.com/apps I can register only if I have "work" or "student" account, but I'm an ISV with gmail. And I have azure subscription with this account. I can create a power bi workspace collection. I guess it should be possible to register my app in Azure portal to get permissions for Power BI. `AAD` -> `App registrations` And then I guess those permissions should be added to apps registration Manifest, but...  but what should be added there?

Comment: Ok, I got it :) (not that it was easy...) you need to have at least one organizational account with power bi subscription - otherwise you don't have power bi service available through required access. One more thing to take in to account - seams like some account related stuff is not available through new Azure portal, and should be done through­ `Classic` portal